# How to create menu item with panels?

Tags: routes, panels

I am using Drupal 7. In one of my projects I used Panels to create a custom layout to one of my pages. As per the needs I also created a menu "item" with the panels. But when i access the menu path of "item" i get the menu to be displayed. When i click the home or other tabs the menu "item" disappears.

Is this a bug in panels or am I missing something that can term me as a novice?

Answer (score 3):

It may or may not be important to understand, but [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) does **not** handle menues at all, it only deals with the layouts their UI. [Page manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools), a part of Ctools, however does handle menues, which is probably what you are using.

To figure out where the issue is:

1. Start by going to admin -> structure -> menues and check, is the expected menu entry in the right menu?  If so, go to step 2. If not, you have a miss-configuration or bug in Page manager.
2. Page manager seemingly has done it's part, and now the question is, how do you render the menu on the different pages? Do you output the menu at all on the page where it doesn't show up?

Comment: Thanks for making a reply Letharion. I get struck with step 1 itself. I don't see menu "item" in my main menu. If you have any idea can you suggest what configuration might have gone wrong. For now i have correct permissions to admin.